# Missing Info.plist value. A value for the Info.plist key 'CFBundleIconName'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, info.plist

Missing Info.plist value. A value for the Info.plist key 'CFBundleIconName' is missing in the bundle id. Apps built with iOS 11 or later SDK must supply app icons in an asset catalog and must also provide a value for this Info.plist key.

i am working native iOS Application. I am already added following line in info.plist.But I don't know, What is reason for that.Please u give answer for my problem. i am using xcode 12.5.1. Latest version of xcode.

[appicon Source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9eMTK.png)

[Target Membership](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUqtF.png)

```
<key>CFBundleIconName</key>
<string>AppIcon</string>
```

Comment: Do you have a AppIcon inside your asset catalog?

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yes i have app icon in my asset catalog.

Answer (score 0):

i am trying lot of day and nights, finally i got solution.

Solutions :
my project created by old xcode versions. its created before 4 years. I am removing all images from asset catalog expect AppIcon and push to testflight its moving. Then I create sample project with my project bundle id. only add images and appicon its moved to testflight above error is not came.

So i am created new project in latest version of xcode and move all files from old project. After moved to testflight. its working.

This is not standard solution. but in my case 100% working. I love apple errors. some time irritating but challenging one.